# Issue in adding image to Openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to implement [Annotorious Openlayers example](http://annotorious.github.io/demos/openlayers-annotation.html) in my web page. I am able to get the map properly but no image is getting loaded in it. I have never used Openlayers before.

The default code is:

```
var baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS("Baselayer", "map_muenster/",
  { layername: ".",
    serviceVersion: ".",
    transitionEffect: "resize",
    type:"jpg" });
```

which I think looks for an images in `map_muenster` directory, but I just want it to display one image.

After looking up a bit, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848307/add-image-to-openlayers-map) Stack Overflow post. I tried adding this layer in the map:

```
var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();

var graphic = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image(
    'Image',
    'https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg',
    new OpenLayers.Bounds(27.418100,35.771100,28.388000,36.558500),
    new OpenLayers.Size(800,255),
    {numZoomLevels: 3}
);

map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
map.addLayers([osm, graphic]);
map.zoomToExtent(new OpenLayers.Bounds(27.418100,35.771100,28.388000,36.558500));
```

but instead of showing the image at `https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg`, the container shows a world map.

How can I add the image to my map and make it annotable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by replacing this line:

```
map.addLayers([osm, graphic]);
```

with this:

```
map.addLayers([graphic, osm]);
```